# Exception handling in gcc compiler in AIX

Tags: aix

I am using AIX 7.1 and gcc 8.3 compiler. I see that exception thrown are not caught if I build with -Wl,-G flag. In the code below, if I do not use the -Wl,-G flag, I see "catch int". With this flag, program cores.

```
void foo()
{
 try {
   throw 1;
 } catch(int&) {
   std::cout << “catch int” << std::endl;
 }
}

int main()
{
 foo();
}
```

My guess is that exception handling is disabled by default and needs to get enabled by some compiler flag. Does anybody else have any experience with this? Please note this is specific to AIX platform.

This is how I am building. The entire code is in 1 file.

bare-08$ g++ -Wl,-G 1.cc

bare-08$ ./a.out

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
IOT/Abort trap (core dumped)

bare-08$ g++ -Wl,-G -lsupc++ 1.cc

bare-08$ ./a.out

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
terminate called recursively
IOT/Abort trap (core dumped)

Without -G option, I get linking error shown below (not in the toy program above, but in my real code).

ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .std::basic_istream >::seekg(long long, std::_Ios_Seekdir)
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .sqrtf
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: std::basic_streambuf >::seekoff(long long, std::_Ios_Seekdir, std::_Ios_Openmode)

Has anyone seen this? I am in a rock and a hard place. Use -G option to get rid of the above linking error, but with that option, C++ exception handling does not work.

Comment: Try to add `-lsupc++` into linkage.

Comment: Adding supc++ was one of the first things I tried, did not help. I did put a breakpoint in __cxa_throw and going through it seems like we get into unwinding error which causes it to call std::terminate.

Comment: Please edit your original post, and describe how did you link the shared object and the main executable. I think you should use -lsupc++ in both cases.

Comment: When creating an executable, why do you use option `-G`? It's meant to be used when creating shared objects.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use option `-G`. If you wish to use some AIX-specific option, use `-brtl`:

```
g++ -Wl,-brtl -o AmarnathShanbhag AmarnathShanbhag.cc && ./AmarnathShanbhag
catch int
```